# Mismatch between the list of owners in Office 365 and Graph Explorer for distribution list groups (and Mail-enabled security groups)

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I added some owners to a distribution list group through the Office 365 admin center. In the Exchange admin center, I can see the proper owners in the Group.

But then when I use the Graph API to get the list of owners of the group, using the /groups/{id}/owners request in the Graph Explorer, the list of the owners assigned to this group is totally different.

Any idea why there is this mismatch?

I encounter the same situation for Mail-enabled security groups.

Thank you in advance

Roksana

The Graph API seems to be totally wrong, giving some invalid user names, and this only on Distribution List groups and Mail-Enabled Security Groups.
It works fine on Office 365 groups.

So a request like this:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/6a61e473-f55c-4fe8-8613-fae7196f9383/owners

will NOT provide the proper list of owners, i.e. the ones you will get through the usual admin center.

Is this a known bug from the Graph API?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. It seems to be a 'how do I use the software' kind of question. Please provide a short code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It's a valid office365 & graph API question, and from what I can see the code sample is already there: graph.microsoft.com/groups/{groupid}/owners is the API request you'd expect to return.